Which Database name Should I Follow When Upgrading Heroku Postgres?
I am following the Heroku documentation for upgrading the version of a Heroku Postgres database.
I am currently on Step 1: Provision a Follower Database
However, when I ran the command heroku pg:info -a APP-NAME, the first line of the output shows two names:
=== DATABASE_URL, ANOTHER_NAME_URL

The documentation says "To begin, create a follower for your database and wait for the follower to catch up to the leader database."
Am I correct in assuming that DATABASE_URL is the primary database, and I only need to run the upgrade command for DATABASE_URL?
Here is the command I plan to run:
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --follow DATABASE_URL --app APP_NAME

Or do I also need to run the upgrade command for ANOTHER_NAME_URL? If so, would the correct command be:
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --follow ANOTHER_NAME_URL --app APP_NAME

